# Capturing fieldname on error in insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get the name of the field that the error is occurring on an  insert in SQL 2014. I am inserting 30+ fields and have wasted hours trying to figure out where the error is occurring at. Seems like a simple debugging feature but the error I get back is

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>
> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

I've gone thru every numeric column in my insert table and tried casting the corresponding data to that correct datatype and cant find the issue.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee]
       (
        [EmployeeID]
       ,[FirstName]
       ,[LastName]
       ,[ManagerID]
       ,[CurrencyCode]
       ,[CountryCode]
       ,[JobTitle]
       ,[Grade]
       ,[IsPlanningEligible] -- BIT
       ,[HireDate]
       ,[LastSalaryReviewDate]
       ,[AnnualSalaryAmt] -- Money
       ,[AnnualSalaryRangeMinAmt] --'NUMERIC'
       ,[AnnualSalaryRangeMidAmt] --'NUMERIC'
       ,[AnnualSalaryRangeMaxAmt] --'NUMERIC'
       ,[PositionInSalaryRange]
       ,[MeritIsEligible] -- BIT
       ,[MeritIsLocked] -- BIT
       ,[MeritBudgetKey]
       ,[LegacyCompany] 
       ,[FTEPct] --'NUMERIC'    
       ,[PreviousYearPerformance] 
       ,[LastIncreasePct] --'NUMERIC'
       ,[LastIncreaseReason] 
       ,[Location]
       ,[CostCenter]  
       ,[ManagerName]
       ,[MeritEffectiveDateByCountry]
       ,[HRBPPersonnelNumber]
       ,[HRBPName]
       ,[HREmployee]  
       ,[LocalPersonnelNumber]
       ,[EmailAddress]
       ,[OrgLevel1]
       ,[OrgLevel2]
       ,[OrgLevel3]
       ,[OrgLevel4]
       ,[OrgLevel5]
       ,[OrgLevel6]         
     )


 /*** IGT STAGING SELECT ***/

  SELECT  LTRIM(Str([Personnel Number], 25, 0))
  ,[Preferred First Name]
  ,[Last Name]
  ,CAST([Manager Personnel Number] AS NVARCHAR(50))
  ,[Currency]
  ,[Country] 
  ,[Job Title]
  ,[Grade]
  ,CAST([Planning Eligible] AS BIT)
  ,[Date of Hire]
  ,[Last Increase Date]
  ,[Annual Base Salary_(as of mm/dd/yyyy) ]
  ,[Minimum of Range]
  ,[Midpoint of Range]
  ,[Maximum of Range]
  ,CAST([Position in Range] AS NVARCHAR(50))
  ,[Merit Eligible ]
  ,[MeritLocked]
  ,[Merit Budget %]
    /*IGT Custom Fields */
  ,[Legacy Company] 
  ,[FTE %]  
  ,[Previous Year's Performance] 
  ,[Last Increase (%)]
  ,[Last Increase Reason]
  ,[Location]
  , CAST([Cost Center] AS NVARCHAR(50))
  ,[Manager Name]
  ,[Merit Effective Date (by Country)]
  ,CAST([HRBP Personnel Number] AS NVARCHAR(50))
  ,[HRBP Name]
  ,[HR Employee (yes/no)]         
  ,[Local Personnel Number]
  ,[Email Address]
  ,[Org Level 1]
  ,[Org Level 2]
  ,[Org Level 3]
  ,[Org Level 4]
  ,[Org Level 5]
  ,[Org Level 6] 

   FROM [IGT_Compensation].[dbo].[IGT_Staging$]
```

Comment: This is probably the most annoying error from sql server. There has been a connect issue for years to fix this. Why they can't simply add the offending column name to the error is beyond me. It is obvious it is available to the engine at the time it happens. This is much like the "data will be truncated" error with no column name.

Comment: Insert statement added

Comment: I was thinking about running SQl Profiler against it but i dont know if that even gets me that fieldname.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of solve is checking your fields with `ISNumeric` function

```
SELECT ID, field1, field2 .., fieldN
FROM yourTable
WHERE 
     ISNUMERIC(field1) = 0
OR   ISNUMERIC(field2) = 0
...
OR   ISNUMERIC(fieldN) = 0
```

Or if you are in an `INSERT` try using `CASE`and change it to a default value.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
Values (
      CASE 
          WHEN ISNUMERIC(field1) = 0 THEN -999
          ELSE CAST (field1 as numeric) 
      END as field1,
      CASE 
          WHEN ISNUMERIC(field2) = 0 THEN -999
          ELSE CAST (field2 as numeric) 
      END as field2,
      ...
```

And then search `YourTable` for `-999`

I know isn't preaty but do the job.